# How to assign different elements of an XML text field into multiple variables using OOP PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I have a text field in a MySQL database table which has a value equal to the below:

```
$foodObject = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <prices>
            <price1>$5.95</price1>
            <price2>$8.95</price2>
        </prices>
        <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
        <calories>
                <A>
                    <A1>650</A1>
                    <A2>652</A2>
                    <A3>653</A3>
                </A>
                <B>
                    <B1>750</B1>
                    <B2>751</B2>
                    <B3>752</B3>
                </B>
                <C>
                    <C1>850</C1>
                    <C2>853</C2>
                    <C3>858</C3>                    
                </C>
        </calories>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>'
```

I retrieved the data into a field called `$foodObject` using object oriented programming in PHP. My goal is to assign the different elements of the `<breakfast_menu>....</breakfast_menu>` into the separate variables such as `$name`, `$price1`, `$price2`, ... and insert them into a table with multiple fields. How to get an output like below using `foreach` and or `swtich` functions in OOP PHP before inserting the data into the new table? thanks for your help.

```
$name = 'Belgian Waffles';
$price1 = '5.95';
$price2 = '8.95';
$A = array(650,652,653);
$B = array(750,751,753);
$C = array(850,853,858);
$calories = array('A','B','C');
```

Answer (score 1):

Paul Crovella posted a wonderful link. I was taking the long way until... 
Antonio Max had a wonderful answer:

```
<?php
    $xml_string = file_get_contents( 'in3.xml' );
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $aFoods = json_decode( $json, TRUE );

    $aFoods = $aFoods[ 'food' ];
    var_dump( $aFoods );
    $iCountFoods = count( $aFoods );
    for( $i = 0; $i < $iCountFoods; ++$i )
    {
        $sFoodName = $aFoods[ $i ][ 'name' ];
        $sPriceOne = $aFoods[ $i ][ 'prices' ][ 'price1' ];
        $sPriceOne = $aFoods[ $i ][ 'prices' ][ 'price2' ];
        var_dump( $sFoodName );
        var_dump( $sPriceOne );
        var_dump( $sPriceOne );

    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Vladimir, I already have the data in the question inside a variable called `foodObject `. The data is not an XML file. I just want to get the `$name`, `$price1`, `$price2`, ... in PHP.

Comment: No problem bud. Here you go.